# Add a video background on a specific component/path

Tags: css, angular, html5-video

I am trying to set a full screen video background which I want to be only visible on the app  "homepage" with no success yet. The first component rendered on the app is HomeComponent.

app-routing-module.ts (only path is shown)

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/accueil', pathMatch: 'full'},
{ path: 'accueil', component: HomeComponent },
{ path: 'ligne/:lineId', component: LineComponent },
{ path: 'ligne/:lineId/station/:stationName', component: StationComponent }
];
```

What I'd like to do is to have the video background only when I'm on /accueil but not on the other paths/components. Is there any way to do that ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the router to your component that contains the div you want to set the background to the video

and then do something like this:

```
if(this.router.url===routeIWant){
    this.custom-bg=true
}else{
    this.custom-bg=false
 }
```

And on the html the following div is the one you wanna set the bg

```
<div [ngClass]="{'customBgClass': custom-bg}">
```

And on the css

```
.customBgClass{
 background: url(your-video-url)
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I'll try this solution when I can and tell you if i manage to do what i want :)